# Android Wear MessageAPI - can't send messages on UI Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I'm following the android wear documentation to send messages from one device to another (https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html)

but I think there's some error in the examples because the send message method throws an IllegalStateException with the following message: **await must not be called on the UI thread**

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that because `await()` blocks the thread.

You want to do this using an asynchronous thread, using for example an `AsyncTask`, like suggested in the **Google Play Services** documentation here: https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html#Sync

And yes, the documentation should be updated to explicate to do tha same for the Wear Api.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of calling `.await()`, use `.setResultCallback()`. For example, ...

```
result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<MessageApi.SendMessageResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(MessageApi.SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Sent message");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks i did not thought this!